# Use Mathematica inside web app?

Tags: web-access, python

My python code running in a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) web application needs to return results from Mathematica, what is the best way to achieve this? Are there any examples of this having been done successfully?

Comment: You will have to provide us with more details.

Comment: I suggest setting up an instant API in Wolfram Cloud and call that. See `CloudDeploy`. The main problem here is not technical but a licensing problem, since serving a website is not, I think, covered by the common licenses like student licenses, home licenses etc.

Comment: It's a localhost on my machine I think that's fine.